# Changing data source dynamically jQuery ui autocomplete on focus an entering characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to get try to use different data source option for the input box using jQuery Autocomplete.

I have input box with id #polysearch. I would like to autocomplete the intput box on focus (just putting the cursor) with source option 'data1' and I would like to autocomplete the input box with source option 'data2' when typing 2 characters. 
Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

By utilising the `source` option for autocomplete, you can customise what array you want to use based on the length of the `request.term` (what the user typed into the box).

You also need to manually invoke the autocomplete's `search` method when the input is focused, to have it open on focus.

Here is the code I had to make this work. [See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/8KsNy/2/).

```
$(function() {
    var data1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    var data2 = 'cat dog fish shark unicorn sasquatch flamingo dingo snake mouse rat'.split(/\s+/g);

    $('#in').autocomplete({
        minLength: 0, // so it shows straight away without typing anything
        source: function (request, response) {
            if ((request.term || '').length <= 1)
               response(filter(data1, request.term));
            else
               response(filter(data2, request.term));
        }
    }).on('focus', function () {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
    });

    function filter(array, searchTerm) {
        var matchingItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].indexOf(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()) >= 0)
                matchingItems.push(array[i]);
        }
        if (matchingItems.length === 0)
            return ['No Matches'];
        return matchingItems;
    }
});
```